# Como se puede sincronizar un progressBar para que avance al mismo tiempo que un proceso se está ejecutando, Swift cocoa

Tags: swift, progressbar

```
@IBOutlet weak var FlashProgress: NSProgressIndicator!

override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  FlashProgress.minValue = 0
  FlashProgress.minValue = 1
}

@IBAction func ShowDates(_ sender:Any){
  DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0.2
  }

  DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0.5
  }

  DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0.1
  }
}
```

**Intenté hacerlo así, una vez la función de ShowDates inicie, el progressbar valla aumentando hasta llegar a 1 que es el Máximo con los valores que puse arriba, pero el progressbar avanza cuando el proceso de la función ShowDates termina, lo cual no quiero que suceda así.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un timer que se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo y va aumentando el valor del progress bar.

Agregué lo siguiente en tu código:

1. Declaramos el timer:

   ```
   var timer: Timer!
   ```
2. Inicializamos los valores máximo, mínimo y seteamos el valor inicial del progress:

   ```
   FlashProgress.minValue = 0
   FlashProgress.maxValue = 1
   FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0
   ```
3. En el `action` del botón voy a crear el timer que se ejecuta cada 1 segundo y va a llamar a la función `moveProgress()`:

   ```
   self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0//Setear en 0 cada que se presiona el botón.
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(moveProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   ```
4. La función suma un valor hasta llegar al límite máximo:

   ```
   self.FlashProgress.doubleValue += 0.1
   if FlashProgress.doubleValue == 1 {
      timer.invalidate()
   }
   ```

El código completo:

```
@IBOutlet weak var FlashProgress: NSProgressIndicator!

var timer: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    FlashProgress.minValue = 0
    FlashProgress.maxValue = 1
    FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0
}

@IBAction func ShowDates(_ sender:Any){
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(moveProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func moveProgress() {
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue += 0.1
    if FlashProgress.doubleValue == 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

El resultado:

[image]

Puedes usarlo igual haciendo una llamada a una API de manera asíncrona y al obtener la respuesta de la API, seteas el valor final del progress y eliminas el timer:

```
@IBAction func ShowDates(_ sender:Any){
    self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 0
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(moveProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Llamada a una API { response in
            //self.FlashProgress.doubleValue = 1
            //self.timer.invalidate()
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Vale amigo, lo haré así. Muchas Gracias :)